# how to enter form fields using my crawler

Tags: java, forms-authentication, web-crawler

i have to crawl a website which has some secure pages,and ask for username and password for login ,once crawler is started it and  it needs to crawl the secure pages so it should ask username and password from user to login so that crawler can crawl the secure pages.when the crawler is loggedin with the user account who is using the crawler it should crawl the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i did some digging and replying to my own question ,this will help others,using Htmlunit it can be done easliy

```
    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https:website name.com/loginpage");
    HtmlForm form = page.getFormBy("login_form");
        HtmlForm formm= page.getForms().get(0);
    formm.getInputByName("SignInEmailAddress").setValueAttribute("your emailid");
    formm.getInputByName("SignInPassword").setValueAttribute("password");
    page = (HtmlPage) formm.getInputByValue("Login").click();
        System.out.println(page);
        System.out.println(page.asText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send a POST request with the correct username/password. Check the form HTML code of a login page for more details, especially the field names.